# Database Strategy for Charting

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have a database that holds events from my application and these tables will be queried later on for charting purposes.

My table is denormalized, i.e.:

```
EventTable:
-EventId
-UserId
-UserName
-EventType
-DataTime
-CompanyId
-CompanyName
```

As it is going to be used for charting, I will be aggregating/pivoting/etc a lot.

Currently everything is being stored in SQL Server.

I would like to know if you guys have any suggestion to what I should be using to facilitate the data extraction from this table.

Sorry if this is not clear enough as english is not my native language.

**UPDATE:**

I will be creating the charts myself on a web application. My plan is to query the database using Stored Procedures and generate the chart using a javascript framework like Kendo UI.

Some of the queries that I'll be performing are:

- 'Quantity of Events' per 'Event Type' each Company had during a period
- Distribution of 'Events Type' a particular Company had during a period

Comment: There isn't anywhere near enough information here. We can deal with the language barrier, that is not an issue at all. However, you really haven't asked a complete question here. You have a denormalized table and you want to get some data out of it.

Comment: what is your charting provider? If it's something like JasperReports/SSRS/Business Objects then you can make a direct connection to the db and get the data out using sql. If not you may need to extract the data first by building a web service layer.

Comment: I've updated the question and added more details to what I am planning to do. Hope it is a bit more clear.